# Can I assign a static class to a variable?

Tags: c#

My question is whether I can assign a static class to another variable (and of what type would that be) ?

Say I have

```
public static class AClassWithALongNameIDontWantTotType{
    public static bool methodA() { stuff }
}
```

and then I have

```
class B{

}
```

Can I make it so that inside of `class B` I can reassign this class to something with a shorter name, like:

```
SomeType a = AClassWithALongNameIDontWantTotType
```

and then be able to do

```
a.methodA()
```

?

I can get out a function by doing something like

```
Func<bool> a = AClassWithALongNameIDontWantTotType.methodA()
```

but I would prefer to have the whole class.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use intellisense you don't have to type the whole name, just the beginning and then tab ;).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that, but I still like when my code is not littered with long names, if there is any way to shorten it :P Looks cleaner!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want this purely for the purpose of avoiding typing long names, you can use an alias

```
using a = SomeNamespace.AClassWithALongNameIDontWantToType;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted :P

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, because you can't have an instance of a static class. You can accomplish what you're looking for through Reflection or dynamic. To do this I created a `DynamicObject` to help:

```
class StaticMethodProvider : DynamicObject
{
    private Type ToWorkWith { get; set; }

    public StaticMethodProvider(Type toWorkWith)
    {
        ToWorkWith = toWorkWith;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, 
        object[] args, out object result)
    {
        result = ToWorkWith.InvokeMember(binder.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
            null, null, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then you'd be able to do

```
dynamic a = new StaticMethodProvider(
    typeof(AClassWithALongNameIDontWantTotType));
Console.WriteLine(a.methodA());
```

But then you wouldn't have intellisense and compile time safety. It's probably a bit of overkill.